# Does the following sentence have both a definite and indefinite noun?

Tags: nouns

Does the following sentence have both a definite and indefinite noun?

Surely with hardship comes ease.

Thanks,

Comment: Never heard of definite or indefinite nouns.

Comment: Where the terms 'definite' and 'indefinite' are used, they are used to refer to concrete ('the tiger snarled angrily'; definite) or generic ('the tiger has been hunted almost to extinction'; indefinite) examples. But this is a general statement associating abstracts (though 'the hardship imprisonment provided ended when he was released, giving way to a period of blissful ease' shows more definite usages).

Comment: 'The man on the Clapham bus was taller than I am, and he wore a red jacket' (definite usages of both 'man' and 'Clapham bus') / 'The man on the Clapham omnibus realises that the risks of vaccination are far less than those of non-vaccination' (indefinite usage).